# what is "make png" command for?

Tags: command-line, make, png

I have a source code that should be compiled to create some executable files.

The code is:

```
#-------------------------
# for executable file 
#-------------------------
executables :
    chmod 754 $(BIN_DIR)*.sh; \
    cd $(SRC_BIN_DIR); make CC=$(CC) CFLAGS="$(CFLAGS)"; \
    make -f makefile2 CC=$(CC) CFLAGS="$(CFLAGS)" FC=$(FC) FCFLAGS="$(FCFLAGS)"; \
    cd BTOP;  make CC=$(CC) CFLAGS="$(CFLAGS)" FC=$(FC) FCFLAGS="$(FCFLAGS)"; \
    cd ../SW; make CC=$(CC) CFLAGS="$(CFLAGS)"; make install; \
    cd ../YHyM_Sup; make CC=$(CC) CFLAGS="$(CFLAGS)"; make cp;
#-------------------------
# option(png related)
#-------------------------
png:
    cd $(SRC_LIB_DIR)image;\make -f makepng CC=$(CC) CFLAGS="$(CFLAGS)";\
    cd ../../bin; \
    make y_asc2png          CC=$(CC) CFLAGS="$(CFLAGS)"; \
    make y_asc2png2mm       CC=$(CC) CFLAGS="$(CFLAGS)"; \
    make y_mkpng_point_facc CC=$(CC) CFLAGS="$(CFLAGS)"; \
    make y_asc2png_all      CC=$(CC) CFLAGS="$(CFLAGS)"; \


#-------------------------
# TODO
#-------------------------
# ./configure script
```

How should I use the `makepng` command to compile it successfully?

Answer (score 0):

The command `makepng` is used to make a png image. There are two main stages. The first is generating an image that is stored in memory. In this case a simple fractal is generated. The image is held in a 1D float array of length width x height. The second stage is then to write the image to an actual file.

To make the command work you have to install the dependencies:

`sudo apt-get install libpng3`

`sudo apt-get install libpng-dev`

See [this](http://www.labbookpages.co.uk/software/imgProc/libPNG.html) for more info

**Note that this is an optional, so you are not obliged to do that**